# Timer implementation in C for deleting a record in linked list once timer expires

Tags: c, timer, linked-list

I need to implement a linked list and each record in the linked list will have "TTL:time to live" variable as one of the members. So every time a record is created in linked list, the TTL is set to some value and timer is started. Once the timer expires the record has to be deleted from the linked list immediately.

I want to know if this could be implemented in C and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest implementation would be to give each record a `live until` (defined as `current time + ttl` as the record is being created) and just ignore all records with `live until < current time`.

That way you get to choose when you'd like to delete the expired records. Maybe you want to do it at the beginning of all functions using the list. Maybe you want to have a single timer, which does it once every second. Maybe some combination of these.

There is most likely no point in having a timer for each record.